# How to go to remote directory in Cygwin?

Tags: windows, networking, cygwin

I'm using the latest version of Cygwin to try to `cd` into a network drive on Windows XP Pro Service Pack 3. The path in Windows Explorer to this directory is something like:

`\\myserver\photos\original`

I tried mounting it to a drive letter ('X') in Explorer, which worked just fine, but then when I ran the command:

`ls /cygdrive/x/`

It just froze there and hung. Any ideas how I can go into this directory and at least taking a listing of the files in there?

Comment: I was able to use "ls /cygdrive/x/" on Windows 7 Enterprise

Answer (score 69):

To add to quack's answer: You can access the network drive also via

```
ls //myserver/photos
```

However, on my machine (Windows Vista) it works only after at first pointing the explorer there `(\\myserver\photos)`  and entering my username and password.

[In the Cygwin docs](https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#unc-paths) they lose a short word about this.

Comment: Awesome. This works without mounting the drive in windows as a letter.

Comment: `ls //VBOXSRV/<vbox share name>/` - for those who wants to access VirtualBox shares through cygwin.

Comment: It also works with MinTTY (git bash)

Answer (score 13):

You're doing it correctly -- this process works on my setup.  The `/cygdrive/X` notation *should* work for any drive that Windows has mounted and given a drive letter.

- Can you browse this network share in Explorer?  (Your question doesn't state so explicitly, so double-check.)
- You can try a standard Windows `cmd` shell (not Cygwin) -- Windows' builtin `pushd` will auto-mount the share to a temporary drive.

  ```
  C:> pushd \\myserver\photos\original

  Z:\original>
  ```

If neither of those work, you've got another problem.  (Is the computer with the network share up?)

If those work but Cygwin still can't view `/cygdrive/X` (or `/cygdrive/z` after your Windows `pushd` test), I'd try rebooting your workstation.  If the problem persists after a reboot, you may have a broken Cygwin installation; I honestly can't think of any other reasons why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! I can browse it in Explorer, actually, and it was definitely up and running. I just tried the `pushd` command and that worked, but not in cygwin. It seems that I can't list any files in any network drive. Is there a tool I need to download from `setup.exe`?

Comment: i can't think of anything in particular; this functionality should *just work*.  i mean, Cygwin is just using regular filesystem access calls, nothing special, so it should be able to list directories and read files on *any* mounted filesystem.  if i were you i'd try uninstalling Cygwin then reinstalling.  if you have an old version, consider reinstalling the latest version (v1.7.x of the cygwin.dll).

Comment: The mounted share is hidden on my setup if mounted _after_ the start of Cygwin. It is shown if I restart Cygwin afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same symptoms.  The problem appeared to be related to running the application in administration mode.  As soon as I turned off the option to 'Run this program as an administrator' and restarted the application I was able to access the network drives via the /cygdrive/ directory.

Note: I'm running Windows Server 2012 R2 but I would bet this would work on windows7 and up.

Note: You must open the properties dialog of the binary itself (ie mintty.exe)  and not the short cut to access the administration option for the application.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I cannot stress enough how HELPFUL THIS ANSWER WAS! ...I would have NEVER thought of that! Woo Hoo! HAPPY! I've been puzzling over this for a LONG time!

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled here with the same problem. I know this is an old post but hope it will help others just in case. I had no luck with the suggested solutions. However this worked for me: cd //remotehost/d$ if the the remote host is a Windows machine.  The dollar sign does the trick.

Comment: The d$ may get you into the root of the D: drive on that machine, if it's not disallowed.  What the OP is looking for is how to get into a specific share on the box.